# Why is my filament pressed together at the nozzle

Tags: filament, nozzle

When I wanted to take out the filament from the extruder, it didn't wanna come out, it was stuck (even when I heated up the nozzle). So I unscrewed the nozzle and it looks like the filament is all pressed together at the top of the nozzle (see picture). What does this mean? I am heaving issues extruding filament from the nozzle, the filament barely comes out and the extruder motor is clicking. Can someone help, please.[image]

Comment: What is the white stuff?  And the cylinder? from the pic it almost looks like you have some tape on the filament letting the glue run downwards towards the nozzle...  sounds crazy, but I remember a guy on youtube having exactly that problem with his CR-10...

Comment: The plastic is twisted, so it's damaged and damaged plastic becomes white.

Comment: could be too soft a filament for a bowden, could be moist filiment, could be a physical obstruction, could be too fast a feed rate, could be too low a temp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per attached picture I can see that the issue source could be:

1. the ptf tube is not inserted to the end of heat-break, or it is not straight-cut at the end - [see this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K9InOVlQrro) for help
2. the cooler on the hotend is not working properly/not installed and heat goes up to the throttle and melts the material
3. an object in the nozzle that blocks the flow (usually a ptf tube particle that probably melted) - clean/replace the nozzle

Comment: I didn't know you needed to put the tube in that far, I'll try that out, thanks

Comment: @YenteCool the main problem is the point number 2 that creates the problem 3, so you will have that plastic worm.

Comment: you can see this problem under this topic https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/4927/hot-end-jamming-very-quickly?rq=1